# Select specific item from multi-object ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel that wraps two lists of different objects: `List<Review>` and `List<DayCommentary>` into `ReviewViewModel`. `List<DayCommentary>` will always be a collection of either 0, 1 or max 2 elements, all with different `DayCommentary.CommentaryFor` (string parameter) values.

In my view, I need to display a textarea for one of the elements in `List<DayCommentary>` in one section of the page and another textarea for another element in another section of the same page.

I tried to achieve this with the code below which throws an error during runtime:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DayCommentary.Select(c => c.CommentaryFor == "Day"), 
new {@class = "form-control commentary", @style = "max-width: none"})
```

Error:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, 
single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

I assume it's not happy with my LINQ select statement.

What is the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do, while still binding to the model for posting back to the controller during `FormMethod.Post`?

Answer (score 1):

```
model.DayCommentary.Select(c => c.CommentaryFor == "Day")
```

This doesn't make sense as it will return a collection of bools.

Perhaps you meant

```
model.DayCommentary.First(c => c.CommentaryFor == "Day").CommentaryFor
```

If you want a text area for each element in your `DayCommentary` collection, use a `foreach` loop on the collection. Let me know if you're not sure how to do this I'll happily add some example code to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using TextArea instead of TextAreaFor, which can allow you to specify whatever value you might want:

```
@Html.TextArea("DayCommentary",
               Model.DayCommentary.Single(c => c.CommentaryFor == "Day").Text,
               new {@class = "form-control commentary", @style = "max-width: none"})
```

Notice that the code above makes a lot of assumptions. First parameter, name, assumes that on the post you expect to receive this value named as "DayCommentary". Second parameter assumes that `DayCommentary` object has `Text` property - obviously you cannot feed the object itself to the method. It also assumes that there will be only one object returned by LINQ query - you cannot bind text area to a list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The biggest takeaway from your comment is: "you cannot bind text area to a list". I should probably rethink my model...

Comment: @illya, well, you can, but not easily. You could also format a list to string with new lines separating individual items, and bind that to text area. Whatever solution you come up with, please post as self answer here, not to leave this thread in unfinished state